# What are ways to send cross-domain request to Gmail feeds?

Tags: javascript, gmail, cross-domain, google-api

I know the url is:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

It seems like gmail API only provides gmail feeds with XML format. How do I get around the situation? This piece of code doesn't seem to work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = res.responseXML;
        console.log(headline);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('failed');
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Letting any random web site read your email would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have

1. Your own site A
2. People login to A and supply gmail credentials
3. Now you want to serve them their gmail email from your own site A

Now typically if you try to make a call to gmail from a page that was served by A most browsers will prevent this cross domain request.

You can implement your own webservice on your server that acts like proxy to make that request to gmail feed and returns the xml to the client.  This way all your requests will be to the same domain A